# Batch Scripting - FOR and IF

Tags: loops, windows-7, batch-file, for-loop

Just new to Batch Scripting and having a problem here: I've been asked to list all the text files whose names are 7 letters long within the whole c:\ drive and ouput it to a file. I can't figure it out.

After endless hours of searching google I've come up with this:

```
for /R C:\ %i in (.\*) do if %~ni==???????.txt echo %i > file.txt
```

Now I understand this is probably wrong due to the fact... it's not working.

Thanks in advance. John W.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do it. You don't really need a batch *file* for this.

```
dir /s /b C:\*.txt | findstr "\\.......\.txt$" > files.txt
```

**Update:**

To make it work for `123\123.txt` use

```
dir /s /b C:\*.txt | findstr "\\[^\\][^\\][^\\][^\\][^\\][^\\][^\\]\.txt$" > files.txt
```

Comment: Ok, this is a bit smarter than my solution

Comment: EXCELLENT! I was on the complete wrong track, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @jeb But I knew you'd be right on it, so I had to work harder :) @JohnW I have added the `$` to the regular expression now to make it more robust.

Comment: @ardshr Hey again xD! I know you've helped a lot and your solution is working for the most part; however, it seems to be adding files with any 7 characters after a slash for example: it will return _1234567.txt_ however it will also return _123/123.txt_ therefor printing any text file with 3 letters in its name in a 3 letter directory. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @JohnW I had this fear. Updated my answer.

Comment: @ardshr EXCELLENT. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would put the code into a batch file, then you have to double the percent signs of the FOR-Loop.
As the FOR /R supports some nice features, like searching for a file-masks, you could use this.

But ???? will find all files with a maximum of the number of question marks not only excact matching.
Therefore I test the filename later, if it has at least 7 characters

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R C:\temp\ %%i in (???????.txt) do (
  set "filename=%%~ni"
  if "!filename:~6,1!" NEQ "" (
    echo has 7 characters %%i
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however, the solution below was a little easier for me to figure out. Not to say yours wasn't straightforward but I was already confused enough. One question though, the 'set' parameter for the FOR command, does it not require a set of files, not the "??????.txt" string?